# PL/SQL- Find second highest salary per department

Tags: sql, subquery

I am stuck on a school project. I need the second-highest salary per department, but without having the third, fourth etc. I am using Oracle SQL. and I need to do it with subquery.
This is the only code I can come up with so far. I can filter all salaries after the highest, but I cant filter only the second highest. I have two statements, that produce the same result at the end.

```
select e.department_id, d.department_name, e.first_name, e.last_name, e.salary 
from employees e inner join departments d
on (e.department_id = d.department_id)
where e.salary <  (select max(salary)
                  from employees e
                  where e.department_id = d.department_id
                  order by d.department_id
                  offset 1 row fetch next 2 row only)
order by e.department_id;
```

Or

select department_id, first_name, last_name, salary
from employees
where salary < any (select max(salary)
from employees
group by department_id)
order by department_id;

Comment: The subquery clause `order by d.department_id` looks suspicious to me. It should be ordered by salay amount descending, isn't it?

Comment: You're using Oracle SQL, not PL/SQL. PL/SQL is an in-database programming language.

Comment: *" I need to do it with subquery"*: any other restrictions on which syntax can be used? (like analytic functions?). Please list *all* restrictions.

Comment: we havent covered the analytic functions yet,  only sorting, single row and multiple rows functions, conditional expressions, and subqueries.